# I run log but log is clean

Tags: vba, logging, vbscript, backup

I run this command in cmd:

```
cscript D:\new.vbs > output.log
```

But when I open log it is almost clean:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
```

I need simple log system to my vbs backup.

Source code of new.vbs (from internet):

```
' Backup folder using 7-Zip
' Written by Steve Allison 2014 - steve@allison.im

Dim fso, rs, shell

' File System Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' RecordSet
Set rs = CreateObject("Ador.Recordset")
' Shell
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Const adVarChar = 200
Const adDate = 7

srcFolder="C:\Customer"
dstFolder="S:\Backup"
backupName="backup"
zipEXE="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

' Number of files to keep
iNum = 5

' Get the date in the correct order. Why does vbscript suck so hard at date formatting?
Function getDateString()
    d = ZeroPad(Day(Now()), 2)
    m = ZeroPad(Month(Now()), 2)    
    y = Year(Now())
    getDateString = y & m & d
End Function

' No printf() in VBScript it seems
Function ZeroPad(int, length)
 If Len(int) < length Then
 ZeroPad = Right(String(length, "0") & int, length)
 End If
End Function

' Sanity checking
If Not fso.FolderExists(srcFolder) Then
 Wscript.Echo "Aborted. Source folder does not exist: " & srcFolder
 Wscript.Quit
End If
If Not fso.FolderExists(dstFolder) Then
 Wscript.Echo "Aborted. Destination folder does not exist: " & dstFolder
 Wscript.Quit
End If
If Not fso.FileExists(zipEXE) Then
 Wscript.Echo "Aborted. 7-Zip program does not exist: " & zipEXE
 Wscript.Quit
End If

' Create suffix of date-time
backupFileDate = getDateString() & "-" & replace(FormatDateTime(now,4),":","")

' File extension
backupFileExt = ".7z"

' Backup path without extension
backupFilePre = dstFolder & "/" & backupName & "_" & backupFileDate

' Full backup path
backupFile = backupFilePre & backupFileExt

' More sanity checking
n = 1
Do While fso.FileExists(backupFile)
 ' Add integeer to file, loop until it doesn't already exist
 backupFile = backupFilePre & "_" & ZeroPad(n, 2) & backupFileExt
 n = n + 1
Loop

'''' Zip Source Folder
' Create shell command
shCommand = """" & zipEXE & """ a -r """ & backupFile & """"
' Change to source directory
shell.CurrentDirectory = srcFolder & "/"
' Run 7-Zip in shell
shVal = shell.Run(shCommand,4,true)

' Check 7-Zip exit code
If shVal > 1 Then
 Wscript.Echo "7-Zip failed with error code: " & shVal
 Wscript.Quit
End If

'''' Remove old backup files
' Add required fields to recordset
With rs.Fields
 .append "filepath", adVarChar, 255
 .append "datelastmodified", adDate
End With

' Get folder object
set rsFolder=fso.getfolder(dstFolder)

' List folder contents to RecordSet
With rs
    .open
    For Each rsFile in rsFolder.files
        .addnew array("filepath","datelastmodified"), array(rsFile.path,rsFile.datelastmodified)
        .update
    Next
End With

' Loop through folder listing recordset
i=0
If Not (rs.EOF and rs.BOF) then
 ' Sort by last modified, newest first
 rs.Sort = "datelastmodified desc"
 ' Move recordset pointer to first record
 rs.MoveFirst
 ' Loop through recordset
 Do While Not rs.EOF
 ' get path from recordset
 dFile = fso.GetFile(rs.Fields("filepath"))
 ' get filename from path
 dFileName = fso.GetFileName(dFile)
 ' Check if backupName is in the filename
 if InStr(1, dFileName, backupName, 1) Then
 i=i+1
 ' wait until >iNum matches
 if i > iNum Then
 ' Delete file, ignore errors
 On Error Resume Next
 fso.DeleteFile rs.Fields("filepath"), true
 On Error Goto 0
 End If
 End If
 rs.MoveNext
 Loop
End If

Wscript.Echo "Backup complete at " & backupFile
```

This code is okay, it works very well but I want log because I run this new.vbs when I leaving my computer and later I want check if everything was OK. Can someone help me?

Comment: Edit your post and add the source code of new.vbs

Comment: Publish (relevant parts of) `new.vbs`.

Comment: Try this way `cscript new.vbs > output.log`

Comment: Source code is here. I try it that way: `cscript new.vbs > output.log` but is not working. Same as first time, nothing in log.

Answer (score 1):

1. Assumption: The `output.log` you look at isn't the `output.log` your command writes to. Check timestamps, look for `output.log` in current directory, delete it and see if it is re-created, use a full file spec after the `>`.
2. Assumption: The last line of your script isn't reached. Put a `Wscript.Echo "Backup started` at the top of your script.
3. Assumption: Something else goes wrong. Debug the script using `cscript //X ...`.